# database Table is not updating c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, sql-insert

I have form and dataGridView connected to table in the database,
when I add records It shows up in the dataGridView, but when I stop running the table returns empty!

here is the code:

```
        string employeeName =  "person";
        string employeeUserName ="person1";
        string emplpyeeNotes = "empty";
        string employeePassword = "123";
        int employeeSalary = 4000;
        try
        {

           SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.StudentManagementDBConnectionString);
           cn.Open();

           string sql = "INSERT INTO Employee (Name,Salary,UserName,Password,Notes) VALUES(@name, @salary, @userName, @password, @notes)";
           SqlCommand exsql = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
           exsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", employeeName);
           exsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salary", employeeSalary);
           exsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", employeeUserName);
           exsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", employeePassword);
           exsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@notes", emplpyeeNotes);
           exsql.ExecuteNonQuery();

           MessageBox.Show("employee added Successfully", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
           this.employeeTableAdapter.Fill(this.studentManagementDBDataSet.Employee);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

Comment: tyr assigning the ExecuteNonQuery to a int variable and see what number u get. Like int i= exsql.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: I wrote:
int x = exsql.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());

It shows the error message @Sas

Comment: you don't check the result of the call so of course it always says it worked.

Comment: ... and the error message is?

Comment: *1. *are you connection strings pointing the correct db *2. *what transactions are in operation. 3. What does the SQL profiler say when you capture the query? 4. What triggers do you have on the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solve was to change the connection string and set it to path of mdf file by copying it from the properties of the dataset.

Comment: Does this solution refer to something you learned from one of the other answers? If so, please mark the answer that best answered your question as accepted, and upvote any answer you found useful. If this solution isn't based on any of the answers, please explain more specifically and include the code, then mark your answer as accepted after a 48 hour waiting period.

Answer (score 1):

Try using parameterized query like this instead:

```
string employeeName = textBoxName.Text;
string employeeUserName = textBoxUserName.Text;
string emplpyeeNotes = richTextBoxNotes.Text;
string employeePassword = textBoxPassword.Text;

SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(global::StudentManagementProject.Properties.Settings.Default.StudentManagementDBConnectionString);

    try
    {
        string sql = "INSERT INTO Employee (Name,Salary,UserName,Password,Notes) VALUES(@name, @salary, @userName, @password, @notes)";
        SqlCommand exsql = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
        cn.Open();
        exsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", employeeName);
        exsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salary", 2000);
        exsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", employeeUserName);
        exsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", employeePassword);
        exsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@notes", emplpyeeNotes);
        int result=exsql.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (result > 0 )
        {
        MessageBox.Show("employee added Successfully", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }else
        { 
          MessageBox.Show("employee insertion failed", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    finally
    {
        cn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Well, yes, he should be, but it's not obvious that's what his actual problem is.  I'm not that well versed in C#/db interfaces yet, but it looks like you _may_ have dropped the 'naturalized'/international-safe string (the `'N'` character in front of some of the strings) - or does the parameterization automatically handle that?  Oh, and you still shouldn't blanket-catch exception.

Answer (score 0):

your database is updating but visual studio is not copying your database from "Solution" directory to "Debug" or "Bin" directory. if you go to your "Debug" directory and open your database file from there you'll see changes there

Comment: right click on your database in "Solution Explorer" and click on copy, then right click on "Debug" folder and click on paste. you may have to show hidden folders in solution explorer.