# How can I add data into a database column that allows NULL?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

Is there any way to add data into database when the is column is checked allow nulls while creating the table in SQL Server 2008?

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;");
String str = "UPDATE abc SET usn = @st1";

con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st1", TextBox1.Text);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
con.Close();
```

Here the column `usn` is checked allow null while creating the table. 
Thanks

Comment: can you be little more specific please?

Comment: I have created a table names abc which consist of one column names usn which is checked allow null while creating table. I just need to save the number which i enter into the textbox by the user when the button is clicked. So is there any possibility of saving the number even when the allow null is checked?

Comment: Any process where you are altering the table from the user interface is a bad idea.   Make the table have the structure you need or make your process handle the existing structure. Why don;t you specify what you are trying to acheive and give us your current table structure in sql code not application code and we can help you find awy to solve your problem that doesn't involve changing the data integerity of the column.

Comment: Sir, I have created a table name data which consist of 8 column namely usnum, name, frstname,lastname,passwrd,address,bldgrp and phonum. While creating the table i checked allow null option for all accept for usnum and name. Once the table was created i manually entered data for usnum and name and left all other fields empty. I want to enter the details for remaining 6 fields based on the usnum condition which user gives as the input.

Comment: So, when user enters the correct usnum i.e one which is already present in the database, it should redirect user to signup page where the user enters the rest of the 6 details and those details have to save in the table data for the particular usnum which user entered. So, I feel that the allow nulls which i assigned to all other 6 causing this problem. Please help!

Comment: The answer to the question you are asking is very simple: Yes. I think you have some other problem that you are not stating in your question

Comment: `TextBox1.Text` will never return `null`.  It the value is empty, it will return `string.Empty` which is still not `null` (or `DbNull`).

Comment: Sir, I tried it but still I am stuck at the same page. Now to make myself understand better, I am trying the same on little more simplified manner. I have one textbox n a button. Now what evr i enter into the textbox n when the button is clicked, the text has to be saved in the database. My code for that is :

Comment: SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;");String str = "UPDATE abc SET usn = @st1";con.Open();SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st1",);cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();}con.Close();Response.Redirect("welcome.aspx");} Please let me know where I am going wrong. The data field usn is checked allow null while creating the table.

Answer (score 0):

To allow nulls means you can also store null values in database. now you are saying that "Is there any possibility of saving the number even when the allow null is checked?" The answer is "Yes". There is no problem in storing values, even if it is allowed null.

Comment: Sir, I tried it. I am not encountered with any error but the data is not getting saved into the database. Please go through the code which i have posted above. Let me know if I am wrong anywhere.

Comment: SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;");
        String str = "UPDATE abc SET usn = @st1";con.Open();
        SqlCommand and = new SqlCommand(alt, con);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st1", TextBox1.Text);
            
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        con.Close();      Any problem with these?

Comment: your values are being updated but visual studio is not updating your database file in "debug" folder. copy your "database" file from "solutoin" directory to "debug" folder and then open the file

Comment: your problem is same as here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038248/database-table-is-not-updating-c-sharp/23039150#23039150

Comment: Sir, I am sorry. I guess I dint explained my question correctly. I will my best to explain you the main problem. I have created a table name data which consist of 8 column namely usnum, name, frstname,lastname,passwrd,address,bldgrp and phonum. While creating the table i checked allow null option for all accept for usnum and name. Once the table was created i manually entered data for usnum and name and left all other fields empty. I want to enter the details for remaining 6 fields based on the usnum condition which user gives as the input.

Comment: So, whn user enters the correct usnum i.e one which is already present in the database, it should redirect user to signup page where the user enters the rest of the 6 details and those details have to save in the table data for the particular usnum which user entered.